# How to disable MenuItem in asp .net with javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, menuitem

I have created a menu

```
<asp:Menu ID="Name1" runat="server" OnMenuItemClick="DoSth_MenuItemClick" Visible="true">
  <Items>
    <asp:MenuItem Text="Function description" Value="Val" ToolTip="ToolTip description" meta:resourcekey="resourceKey">
    </asp:MenuItem>
  </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

And now I want to enalbe/ disable dynamically MenuItem with JavaScript
I tried to do it with the following JavaScript function

```
function hideMenu() {
  var menu = $get('<%=Name1.ClientID %>');
  menu.getItems().getItem(0).set_enabled(false);
}
```

I got menu object however it is HTMLTalbeElement and then it fail in the second line.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can disable a menu item. 
As it rendered as anchor tag.
As I think you can set it to `javascript:void(0);`

You can set the `css-class` for your menu and submenu.
And use jquery to find the menu and set it's URL to `javascript:void(0);`